# Creating a custom multi-key HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, extend

I have been trying to create a custom `HashMap` which contains 2 keys.
The user creates an object of my class with two parameters `K` and `V`. The class is made of 2 `HashMaps`: natively extended `<Integer, V>` and key storage `<K, Integer>`.
So basically, there are 2 keys for each value: `K` and `Integer`.

When the user wants to get an item, he can retrieve both by using `K` key or `Integer` key. So, for example, if user uses `K` then the system looks up in `keyTable` for an Integer with such key and then uses that `Integer` to find the value `V`

```
public class KeyMap<K, V> extends ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, V> {

    private HashMap<K, Integer> keyTable = new HashMap<K, Integer>(10);

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        if (key instanceof V) {
            return super.get(keyTable.get(key));
        }
        return super.get(key);
    }

}
```

However, I am have never done parameterization before therefore I cannot understand what's the problem - I am getting `Cannot perform instanceof check against type parameter V. Use instead its erasure Object instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime` on line `if (key instanceof V) {`.

Is it even possible to achieve the system I want?

Comment: Don't subclass; encapsulate. http://books.google.com/books?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC&lpg=PR1&dq=effective%20java&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Due to type erasure, you need to accept a `Class<K>` instance.

Comment: Sounds like you want a bimap - http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Comment: @SLaks what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use parametrized types (K and V) in any operation performed at runtime (e.g the `instanceof` operator). In Java all parametrization information is used at compile-time and then essentially removed from the compiled code. This removal is referred to as type erasure. [1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

I suggest you don't rely on the type of the key to determine which HashMap to look in and instead see if the key is a valid key for the first HashMap, and if not, try just the second. Keep in mind that K could be of type Integer, meaning that both key types could be identical.

Comment: How to test if the key is valid key for a HashMap?

Comment: One way is to use the HashMap's containsKey(Object key) method. If that returns false, the key is not valid for that HashMap as no value is associated with that key. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Oh, what I meant is if it's possible to check if the HashMap keys are String or Integer type. Because for example, if I use String as a key for Integered Keys, it will not work.